# Font Awesome icon hover effect from top to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I'm using Font Aewsome for my social icons, working with Bootstrap 3.

I want a hover effect like this one on the bottom: [example](http://mex10.dlr.de/)

I have a list for my social icons :

```
<ul class="social-buttons">
    <li class="youtube"><a href="#" title="Follow us on Youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#" title="Follow us on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    <li class="xing"><a href="#" title="Follow us on Xing"><i class="fa fa-xing fa-lg"></i></a></li>
    <li class="rss"><a href="#" title="Check out our RSS"><i class="fa fa-rss fa-lg"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

For my CSS i have this:

```
.social-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  left: 70%;
  top: 6px;
}

.social-buttons li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
  position: relative;
}

.social-buttons li a {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  display: block;
}

.social-buttons-footer {
  position: relative;
  left: -49px;
}

.social-buttons-footer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.social-buttons-footer li a {
  padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  display: block;
}

.fa-youtube, .fa-twitter, .fa-xing, .fa-rss {
  color: #000000;
}
.fa-lg:hover{
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fa-2x{
  color: #000000;
}
.fa-2x:hover{
  color: #ffffff;
}


// Hover Effect ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.youtube a:hover{
  background-color: #db2c2c;
  -webkit-animation: toBottomFromTop 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: toBottomFromTop 0.3s;
  animation: toBottomFromTop 0.3s;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.twitter a:hover{
  background-color: #83d0f5;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.xing a:hover{
  background-color: #a2d123;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.rss a:hover{
  background-color: #fe9c01;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```

I have searched google the last few hours and i could only find examples where they use sprites or anything like that. I don't really know how to do it. Where should i put the icon that should be exchanged when hovered ?
I know how to do it with sprites - there i use the position. But how do i use it here? I tried something else for the youtube hover: but that looks like a big bug! 
Could someone teach me or tell me where to find a tut? would be nice.

Comment: a jsfiddle would be awsome

Comment: Sorry forgot this! 
Here it is: 

http://jsfiddle.net/lenchenx3/hMavK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have build the effect you need [here on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4VB7/).

You just have to add your AwsomeFont items now.

I have added `overflow: hidden;` to the parents and moved the single elements with `margin: -x px 0 0 0` on an hover event.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I totally didn't think of the margin position! 
i'll try it ASAP :)